# Using example.net instead of sub domains for AD (2016)?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

From my research so far, it’s not recommended to use example.com as a domain/forest for AD due to split brain issues, website, and direct access issues.

It’s recommended to use corp.example.com instead. However, if we have example.net could we use this instead without facing any of the common issues for our AD design?

This would allow us to reduce the length of our FQDN, separate our .com (public) from .net (private).

Comment: Gonna share with you my experience. Early in my learning I built a production network using the same public domain for my internal AD domain. Since then I have built and managed dozens of business networks - all of which have used things like .local or other different combinations. After over 10 years the network I built using the same domain name internally and externally continues to be the most compatible site yet! Split DNS is actually a positive and as services get more hybrid/cloud oriented it just works.

Comment: I’m trying to avoid split dns so users can access our website without having to type www.  Since using our .net is not our main site, I’m definitely leaning towards it for just AD.

Comment: Good point. The network I spoke of has a .com website and everything else is .net. I think the most useful aspect is having the users email address match their AD credentials also.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you could, but why? Stick to the current best practice of using an unused **subdomain** of your public domain name, whether it be a .com, a .net, or something else. You might find that in the future you want to use your .net TLD on the internet and then you'll face the issues you've pointed out in your question.

Comment: Good point but I can’t see any compelling reason not to continue using our .com for all services and .net for internal only services. Even if we do have some external, it likely would be sub domains anyway.

Comment: Of course you can do whatever you want, but most people who manage AD for a living would disagree with you.